# Connecting Trimble Geo7x to ArcCollector

Tags: gps, arcgis-collector, trimble, windows-10, ipad

I'm looking to link a Trimle Geo7x GPS unit to ArcCollector on Ipad or Windows 10. Is there a way to link these these devices easily or do they not play well together?

Answer (score 1):

The Trimble Geo7x is **not** listed on the supported equipment list:

- https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ios/create-maps/gps-receiver-support.htm
- https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/android/create-maps/gps-receiver-support.htm
- https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/windows/create-maps/gps-receiver-support.htm

Not that you asked, but it does work with a Trimble R2  as listed, with the [GNSS Status App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gnss-status/id932189198) or [GNSS Status App](https://www.trimble.com/globalTRL.asp?nav=Collection-109385).

Answer (score 1):

The Geo 7X does not have a bluetooth module that is supported by Apple iOS. You would not be able to connect the two and have the Geo 7X send NMEA data to the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous replies have said, the Geo 7x does not have an iOS-supported Bluetooth module.  R2 and PG200 / R1 are iOS-compatible.

But you can use Geo 7x with applications on Windows 10, assuming the applications use NMEA data (I don't know what ArcCollector uses.)  Download the Geo 6000 GNSS Connector utility from the Trimble web site, GNSS Collector lets you send data from the NMEA port on the Geo 7x (Com2) to another Com port - the physical USB-to-serial port is Com1, Bluetooth would usually be Com5 for Outgoing port (you initiated pairing from the Geo 7x) or Com9 for incoming port (you initiated pairing on the Windows device).